# Get next time when TimerTask is scheduled to run

Tags: java, timer

So I have a repeating TimerTask that runs every x number of seconds (I say x as it can be changed by the user)

I also need to add a UI feature as "time until next execution" in seconds. I could do something where I store an AtomicInteger which I increment every second, and then do some other checking of that integer for if I want to actually 'run' the task. However I'm ideally looking for a simpler way (for example, if I run the task every second but the actual code should be running every 566ms, it won't work properly). I've taken a look at TimerTask#scheduledExecutionTime, but that returns the last time it's run. Is there an easier way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate`

here is simple example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduledThreadPoolExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10);

        ScheduledFuture<?> task = scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            System.out.println("task");
        }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            System.out.println("until " + task.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        }, 500, 700, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow();
    }
```